# Filtering letter combinatons

Tags: excel, filter, combinations, formula

Hi – I’m looking for help for the following problem.
I have a utility operating that gives me all the combinations for a set of letters (or values). This is in the form of 8 choose n, ie there are 8 letters and I can produce all the combinations for sequences where I want no more than 4 letters. So n can be 2, 3, or 4

Now here it gets a bit more complex: the 8 letters are made up of three lists or groups. Hence, A,B,C,D;E1,E2;F1,F2

As I say, I can get all the 2, 3 and 4-sequences without a problem. But I need to filter them so that I get combinations (or rather can filter the result) where I only want letters in the result that ensures I get (in the n=2 condition) at least one from A,B,C,D and one from either the E set or the F set.

So, as a few examples, where n=2

AE1 or DF2… is ok but AB or E1E2 or E1F1… is not ok

Where n=3 the rules alter slightly but it’s the same principle

ABE1, ABF1, BDF2 or BE2F1… is ok but ABC, ABD, AE1E2, DF1F2 or E1E2F1… is not ok.

Similarly, where n=4

ABE1F1, ABE1F2… is ok but ABCD, ABE1E2, CDF1F2 or E1E2F1F2… is not ok.

I’ve tried a few things using different formulas such as with Match and Countif but can’t quite figure it out. So would be very grateful for any help.

Jon

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find an approach to this problem that takes some of the messiness out of it. There are two factors that make this a bit awkward to deal with

```
(a) Combination of single letters and bigrams (digrams?)

(b) Possibility of several different letters / bigrams at each position in the string.
```

It's possible to deal with both of these issues by classifying the letters or bigrams into three groups or classes

```
(1) Letters A-D - let's call this group L
(2) First pair of bigrams E1 & E2 - let's call this group M
(3) Second pair of bigrams F1 & F2 - let's call this group N.
```

Then we can make a list of the allowed combinations of groups which as far as I can work out is something like this

For N=2

```
LM
LN
```

For N=3

```
LLM
LLN
LMN
```

For N=4

```
LLMN
```

(I don't know if LLLM etc. is allowed but these can be added)

I'm going to make a big assumption that the utility mentioned in OP doesn't generate strings like AAAA or E1E1E1E1 otherwise it would be pretty useless and you would be better off starting from scratch.

So you just need a substitute that looks like this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"A","L"),"B","L"),"C","L"),"D","L"),"E1","M"),"E2","M"),"F1","N"),"F2","N")
```

And a lookup in the list of allowed patterns

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$D$2:$D$10,0))
```

and filter on the lookup value being TRUE.

[image]

Comment: Many thank you for looking in to this. I'll go through it and see if it works over the weekend - looks to be in the right ballpark.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works really well on my data - and the assumption you made about useless combinations is correct. What I need to do now, though, because it is very specific for the letters used, is extend it for any grouping. So, still with three groups (ie resulting in LMN), if instead of, say, ABC I might have PQX or something else. And the same kind of approach for the other groups.

Comment: OK good that the idea basically works. The main sticking point to making it more general is the SUBSTITUTE which is already quite long and is very specific to the set of symbols that you're using. It might be a bit easier if you've got a recent version of Excel where you can use TEXTJOIN to join an array of letters to build the classified pattern more flexibly.

Comment: Of course you can put cell references in the SUBSTITUTE instead of just literals, like SUBSTITUTE ...A2,X1,Y1),X2,Y2)... where cols X & Y contain the values you want to substitute.

Comment: The latter approach works well (I was getting stuck before by trying to use the form SUBSTITUTE(A2, X1:Y2...) ... But anyway, though it would be nice to use less 'SUBSTITUTE' as it gets a bit confusing as you add more, the solution is just what I needed. Your help - and the last clarification - is very much appreciated.